# BigQuery: result to my daily query is now NULL since March 15th

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

This question/bug is mainly for the Google BigQuery team.

I have a daily report in Tableau that connect to a Google BigQuery live Connection. This report has been running for over a year without problems. Since March 15th however, the report is no longer working and the result of the gbq queries generated by Tableau now returns 'null'.

Note: The version of Tableau and version of the BigQuery driver have not changed for over a month. So, nothing has changed on our side. I have also checked in the Query History and the generated queries have always been the same in the last weeks.

One simple query that is generated by Tableau and that now returns 'null' looks like this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN 1000000 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE FLOAT([log_time]) / 1000000 END) 
AS [none_Calculation_0500516094317075_ok] 
FROM [GDT.MissingItems] [sqlproxy] 
GROUP BY 1
```

This query comes from a simple calculated field created in Tableau that is divided by 1000000 and is cast to a INT. The job_id is job_ydTIq1c_ydnyua4s4SW3zJj00fs

This looks to me like something has changed recently and that is causing the query to now return 'null' instead of what it should return. This is a big problemfor us as we are using this report for operational purposes.

I posted my question/problem in Stackoverflow as mentioned in the Google BigQuery Support page: 
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/support

Comment: What version of Tableau Desktop/Server are you using?

Comment: Tableau Desktop and Server, version 8.1.5. I have the same problem on the Desktop and on the Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the incorrect application of an optimization in the query execution engine. It has been fixed and we expect to release the fix today (it is possible that the fix won't go live until monday, because we often try to avoid making production changes last minute before the weekend).

The workaround in the meantime would be to use 0.0 rather than null in the case statement.

Comment: Thank you very much Jordan for your quick response, it is really appreciated!!  As for the workaround, in my case it is a little difficult to do it since I have no control on the application(Tableau) and the driver (Simba) that generates the query. I will wait for the fix. Thanks!